.NET Core function app "keepwarm" timetriggered app crashes upon execution
In my small .NET Core function app, I am registering my program.cs like this:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        var authOptions = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OidcAuthOptions)).Get<OidcAuthOptions>();

        services
            .AddTransient<PrintDocumentAction>()
            .AddTransient<OpenDocumentAction>();

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

And I am adding my time triggered app like this:
public class KeepWarm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// KeepWarm, runs twice every minute; can also trigger storages (configfile)
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IOptions<ApplicationOptions> _options;
    private readonly ILogger<KeepWarm> _log;

    public KeepWarm(IOptions<ApplicationOptions> options, ILogger<KeepWarm> log)
    {
        _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        _log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
    }

    [Function(nameof(KeepWarm))]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("1-2 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer) // Run twice per minute at sec 1 and 2
    {
        var functionAppUrl = _options.Value.FunctionAppUrl;
        _log.LogInformation($"Start querying endpoints (BaseUrl={functionAppUrl})");

        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(functionAppUrl) })
        {
            var endpoints = new[] {
                "echo",
            };

            var tasks = endpoints.Select(async (endpoint) =>
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
                _log.LogInformation($"Called {endpoint} with status code {response.StatusCode}");
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }
}

The endpoint is shown in the console:

but upon execution, it immediately crashes:

The other endpoints work; whats the issue with this one?
Best
J

Did you check the exception? It complains that a Null was passes to a Uri constructor at line 31. Where does FunctionAppUrl come from?

Is this an Azure Functions app? Have you stored the values you want in its configuration?

yes, the url is null; i dont know about the config; i just want to run this function app once every minute on prem,..

Why did you create an Azure Function if you want to run it on-prem? None of the Azure Functions features will work.

what will you reccomemd me using instead of the azure function and the storage emulator in the background?

The question is unclear. Why would you want to use the emulator? You could just create a simple console application with a timer. In any case this code is trying to use the Options pattern for loading strongly typed objects from .NET's configuration.

Did you copy some existing code and tried to modify it to make it work? What you're trying to do is similar to killing a fly with a cannon. If all you want is to execute some GET's you can create a batch file that calls them using curl and schedule it to run every 2 minutes

Or maybe not - if you want to keep an Azure site up, keep in mind you're paying for active hours. If the site has so little traffic it goes to sleep, you'll end up paying for a lot of idle time

It's visible in your log that functionAppUrl is null or empty:

I don't see registration of ApplicationOptions in your application startup, do you bind it somewhere?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0
I guess that this property might be not received from your config source(whatever that is).

yes, i was in a missunderstanding regarding the use of the function; i will now use a different backgroundservice. thank you!
